How to make LaTeX look into 'cls' subfolder for additional files? (VS Code)
I have this file structure:
C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Documents\Master\Thesis\
├── cls\
│   └── ugent-doc.cls
│   └── eb-en.pdf
│   └── ugent-en.pdf
└── main.tex
│
└──latexmkrc

And I have this line in my main.tex file:
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,faculty=eb,language=en,doctype=article]{ugent-doc}

In the latexmkrc I have this:
$ENV{'TEXINPUTS'} = './cls//:' . (exists $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'} ? $ENV{'TEXINPUTS'} : '');

Still, I get this error: File `ugent-doc.cls' not found.
Can anyone help me? I want it to look in the subfolders for certain files...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you could try putting the full path  not just ./cls// as the short form depends on the working directory when  vs code invokes latexmk, alternatively and simpler put the cls file in your local texmf tree which is probably ~/texmf/tex/latex/ugent/ugent-doc.cls then you would not need to set TEXINPUTS
